# multiple value in external data column

Tags: bcs

We need to store multiple value from external source in the one column. Same multiple lookup.

Is there any exiting way to do it?

If no, i think about developing custom entity piecker, but it need time to development. Where are might be more effective ways. I will thank for some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this requirement you could use either BCS (Business Connectivity Services) or a custom populated Term Set (timer job that migrates data).

Be aware that BCS has some limitations both in data amounts and doesnt work with Content Type Hub. Term Sets also has boundaries (i believe its 30.000) terms per term set.

Comment: Thanks for answer! We make same decision, but make custom field according to additional requrements

Comment: Careful with custom fields. They are not compatible with Office, Data Sheet View, SharePoint Workspace and alot of other stuff, and should generally be avoided

Comment: Thank for comment:) We awared about it

Comment: @AndersRask: I'm having the same requirement than IAfanasov. Your suggestion to use a populated term set looks like to solve a great number of problems, however, using this technique, we loose the ability to display other columns... right ? If I'm right, do you have any suggestion to keep this behavior (choosing one item, and displaying several of its column) ?

Comment: If you do not need to associate more than one item per list, BCS field is an option.
Just remember that you need to associate it on list level as a field in the list content type (like rating and enterprise keywords). This field will be ignored by CT hub.
Alternatively taxonomies can be "hacked" to use label as carrying relevant data (like ProductId as primary and ProductName as label) but now we are really abusing Taxonomy fields ;-) Term sets isnt ment to carry data as such, but be a list of words (like a dropdown)