# Sharepoint External Data field with multiple values

Tags: 2010, list, development, column, business-data-catalog

I need to create a list column which contains external data (from BDC). The field has to contain multiple values. But I haven't found a way how to make a external-data-field take multiple values.

Creating such a multi-value field is possible by using the Column-Properties "**allow multiple selections**" in a user content type. However, creating a column using external data I do not have the ability to add a multi-value column.

It should look like this, just from a external data source (BDC/BCS): 
[image: multi-value field]

Does anyone know how to handle such a situation?

My Environment:
SharePoint 2010, Visual studio 2010, SharePoint Designer

Comment: Can you get the standard and limited form code? So we can compare the two; it's likely theres a little change you can make to your current form.

Comment: Do you mean the code from the "NewItem" and "EditItem"-forms? Until now I'm using the standart forms. Sorry, I can't follow, what do you recommend to combine?

Comment: I believe this question addresses the same point http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26910/multiple-value-in-external-data-column or if you want the InfoPath way, see here http://aanuwizard.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/creating-multiple-value-lookup-to-external-list-using-infopath/

Comment: I mean the snippet for the form that allows you to select multiple selections, and the form that only allows for one. There may be a simple change in title etc

Comment: @RyanS I can't find anything that helps me allong. But if you like I post the code

Comment: @C.Marius Thanks for your answer! I found this post too, but it wasn't realy solved. I thought, perhabs there is a solution or a workarraound or something else. The infopath is just somethin like a multiselect combobox and wouldn't work in my situation.

Comment: Does the form just not handle multiple values, or does validation throw a flag?

Comment: @RyanS It's the bcs. For a better understanding: If you create a new column from the User-Contenttype you are able to select "allow multiple selections". Than you are able to select multiple users in just this field. If I create a new column from type ExternalData I'm do not have the possibility to activate "allow multiple selections". So it is just possible to select one item instead of multiple items.

Answer (score 4):

You can not allow multi values when using a lookup to a external list.

[image: http://i48.tinypic.com/19w9k0.png]

More info about BCS and its limitations can be fount at:

http://www.slideshare.net/orbitone/share-point-2010-bcs

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/07/bcs-external-list-limitations

Maybe, you could be able to work around this issue using custom field types for example. But not with OOTB BCS.

Comment: Nice, this totally worked :) Great work, Frederik!

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SharePoint Lookup does not supports it. You can try to use commercial add-ons. For example, Sparqube Lookup Extra field type allows multiple values when lookup items from External List.
http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Lookup-Column